# Html5 audio player won't display in iOS app using meteor

Tags: ios, html, audio, meteor, simulator

I'm am trying to build a simple music app using meteor as my framework. I'm using html5 audio tags as my player. Everything works and displays completely fine in my browser but when testing on the iOS simulator all i get is a black screen with a giant gray play button that does not work.

I'm wondering if this is a meteor problem or if iOS limitations are too robust in order for the html5 audio player to display correctly.

If anyone knows the solution to this please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with the html5 video element. I will share my findings for that as it sounds like the same issue for the audio tag.

## iOS web app and Cordova

For iOS just add “webkit-playsinline” next to your audio tag as done below for video:

```
<video webkit-playsinline>
  <source src="mySource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

## Cordova

For a Meteor Cordova iOS app you also need to add the following to *mobile-config.js* to set the cordova *config.xml* settings:

```
App.setPreference('AllowInlineMediaPlayback', true);
```

You can read up some more about this on http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/78586868260/getting-the-html5-video-tag-to-work-in-cordova-for

If that does not work you can go with the following cordova plugin which supports audio playback: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media

Example from the plugin docs:

```
 var myMedia = new Media("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3")
  myMedia.play({ numberOfLoops: 2 })
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Riaan

Comment: Hey, is mobile-config.js a file already located in Xcode or is it a file I have to create manually because I can't seem to find it and if so where do I place it?

Comment: Just create the *mobile-config.js* file in your Meteor base directory. This is only necessary if you are using Cordova. Meteor uses that file to set properties in the Cordova *config.xml* file included in the iOS build. Include the *webkit-playsinline* for a Cordova app and a normal web app. See [link](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to do the trick. You mind checking out my repo and helping me out from there?

Comment: Hi @DDavis25, Yes anytime - where can I find the repo? Just create a minimal repo for this issue. Just for some clarity - are using Meteor Cordova or just browsing from your mobile device to the url?

Comment: I'm creating a html5 audio player playlist using Xcode to test my project so I think the Cordova package is added to the project. I created a minimal repo here: https://github.com/DDavis1025/meteorplayer

Comment: Hi, Sorry I havnt had time to look at this yet - will in this week.

Comment: Okay rian no problem. This is a problem much more complicated than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Audio is not supported on most mobile devices. Check out the documentation at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio for more information. iOS does not support a lot of the new HTML5 Media elements and APIs at this point. The only mobile browser that supports HTML5 audio is Firefox Mobile. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Chris, Well i got the audio to play in the background of my app when I put it my songs into a playlist and also it plays when it goes into full screen mode. Does this still mean it will be impossible to display the audio player as the regular looking player?

Comment: Yes, some things will work on iOS, but it isn't fully supported yet. If you are using the correct audio files listed in the link I provided you CAN get playback. You should consider creating your own controls if this is the only stumbling block you are encountering. Otherwise, please provide some source or screenshots so I can better understand the exact issue you are having.

Comment: The display of the controls really is my main issue besides one slight difficulty in my playlist. Here's the question I posted yesterday about my Html5 playlist:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807082/html5-audio-playlist-does-not-work-properly-or-display-in-meteor-js-ios-applicat      Everything works 100% okay in the browser just not the iOS simulator

Comment: Unfortunately I don't  think I can help you out more then. If all you care about are the controls, I suggest building your own UI in html and linking that up to the player via javascript. I haven't personally tried getting the `<audio controls>` to work on iOS. If you want to do a sanity test, I suggest setting up a local test URL and navigating to it in the emulator to see if it can load the controls outside of Meteor. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I've looked around for some bootstrap players but haven't seem to get any that work well with meteor so far. But I do appreciate the help and answers and will continue to do research. Thank you